# Переместить элемент PHP-массива на другой индекс

Tags: php, массивы

Есть простой масссив на РНР например:

```
$array = array('three','one','two','four','five');
```

Нужно переместить первый элемент на другой индекс например

```
$newKey = 2;
```

Пробую вот так:

```
$array[$newKey] = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);
echo implode(',',$array);
```

Но тот элемент который имел индекс 2 просто удаляется. Как поставить первый элемент на его место а его и остальные после него сдвинуть на один шаг правее?

Должно получится:

```
one,two,three,four,five
```

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы элемент с индексом 0 оказался на, допустим, 2, то в любом случае на его месте должно что-то остаться, иначе его индекс после замены уже не будет 2, а будет `n-1`.... Вам на место первого элемента нужно поместить тот, вместо которого вставляется первый элемент или нет?

Comment: то есть по сути в итоге вам нужно просто поменять два элемента массива местами, так?

Comment: Получается что элементы индекс которых меньше `$newKey` должны сдвинутся на один шаг левее, элемент индекс которого совпадает с `$newKey` и все элементы которые после него — на один шаг правее, а между ними вставить тот элемент который был первым. Обновил вопрос (что должно получится)

Comment: @stckvrw У вас пример неудачный. Видя две строки что было и что должно стать кажется, что достаточно просто поменять местами 2 элемента массива. Но вы, кажется хотите большего. Сделайте пример посложнее. Меняйте не первые 2 элемента а скажем 1 и 3й и напишите что должно быть в этом случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
 $array = array('three','one','two','four','five');

 $tmp=array_shift($array);      # Удаляет первый элемент массива, возвращая его
 array_splice($array,2,0,$tmp); # Вставляет элемент после 2-го элемента, удалив с этой позиции 0 элементов

 echo implode(',',$array);
?>
```

И можно даже одной строкой, без временных переменных:

```
array_splice($array,2,0,array_shift($array));
```

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов:

```
$array = array('three','one','two','four','five');
$newKey = 2;

$left_part = array_slice($array, 1, $newKey);  
$right_part = array_slice($array, $newKey + 1);  
$new_arr = array_merge($left_part, array($array[0]));
$new_arr = array_merge($new_arr, $right_part);


echo implode(',',$new_arr);
```

Comment: Не пойдет. У вас замена местами, а в вопросе перемещение только одного элемента со сдвигом остальных затрагиваемых.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, не совсем то. Вы просто меняете элементы местами. А мне нужно их "раздвинуть" и вставить между ними тот который был первым. См. мой комментарий и обновленный пример

Comment: @stckvrw Подправил. Один вариант накидал

Comment: Ничего не меняется

Comment: @stckvrw просто в `implode` не тот массив записал. Но смотрю есть решения получше))

Comment: @Visman Я написал ответ раньше, чем автор обновил вопрос свой на новый

Answer (score 1):

Заменяем элемент $newKey на два и удаляем первый

```
$newKey=2;
$array = array('three','one','two','four','five');
array_splice($array, $newKey, 1, array($array[$newKey], $array[0]));
unset($array[0]);
print_r($array);
```